# How to get a Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

My question is about how to get a Monero wallet on my computer from a download on this web site?  Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this page to get started with Monero:

https://getmonero.org/get-started/using/

As the header says:

> Transacting with Monero can be made easy. This page is designed to guide users in that process.